# ERROR 503 when using the google admin sdk directory

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-account

We have an automated batch that runs every day to synchronise users between an internal users MYSQL table and google accounts. Since the end of may (2014/05/29), this batch is failing because each request to create or update users results in the following response :

> 503 Service Unavailable { "code" : 503, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Backend Error", "reason" : "backendError" } ], "message" : "Backend Error" }

The only information I could find in the help center about 503 errors is that it comes from a quota being reached. Looking at the graphs available in the API console shows that we are well below the defined quota (150K/day), over the last 28 days period we did not even reach 0.05% of that quota.

Has anyone got an idea why we get that error since the quota doesn't seem to be the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Etienne Bömcke

Comment: Google APIs also have 'per-user' limits (https://developers.google.com/console/help/?csw=1#usercap) and I think some of their APIs may have a default limit of 1 request/second/user which in the case of a batch task might easily be consumed up. Although, it looks like your automated task had been running okay before the end of May so I'm not sure if this is a good lead.

Comment: I reviewed the per-user limits and we're still well below that. The relevant one is currently set to 15 per user per second, and there is a hard-coded delay of 5s between two successive requests in our application. Furthermore, even the first request fails, which would not be explained by a quota issue.